# How do I set UISlider to have only one track image rather than using a minimum track image and a maximum track image in Swift?

Tags: swift, image, interface, uislider

Hello I was wondering how to just have one track image for my customized slider. I am having an issue where if I set the minimum track image and the maximum track image using the same image, my slider has a gap in the thumb image such as in this picture. [image: in this picture].

This is my custom class UISlider code.

```
  import UIKit

class NightVisionSlider: UISlider {

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)



      self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named:"Night Vision Slider Knob3.png")!, for:.normal)

        let trackingImage = UIImage(named:"Night Vision Bar 2.png")!

      self.setMinimumTrackImage(trackingImage, for:.normal)

       self.setMaximumTrackImage(trackingImage, for:.normal)

    }


}
```

How can I just have one complete tracking image, so my slider doesn't have this flaw?

Comment: I don't think you can without nearly *creating* your own slider. If I were you, before doing that, rethink your thumb image. Otherwise, I'm thinking you need to subclass the critical things for your slider and then build your own with a single track. *"It's not a flaw [bug], it's a feature."*

Comment: Thank you very much @dfd for clarifying about this issue.  I just found a way out of this issue is to create an imageView of the tracking Image behind the slider and then setting the alpha of the bar/tracking part to 0.  Do you think this is a good approach or should I try to create my own slider?

Comment: I say if it works, do it. I want to make a distinction (from my earlier comment) between "creating" and "subclassing". Since subclassing would *still* involve a max/min track, I was thinking you may need to create a slider, including all the views and the properties you need. I'd suggest that if you have this style slider working with the UIImageView and you may reuse it elsewhere, consider subclassing it (as NightVisionSlider?) and add the image to the subclass. You could even add properties for that image and thumb image, make the whole thing IBInspectable and distribute it.

Comment: I need research more about UIDesign and subclassing then. I really appreciate your help and you helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider
{

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named:"Night Vision Slider Knob3.png")!, for:.normal)

       let trackingImage = UIImage(named:"Night Vision Bar 2.png")!

       self.setMinimumTrackImage(trackingImage, for:.normal)

       self.setMaximumTrackImage(trackingImage, for:.normal)

    }
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        super.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2  //Do something additional if you want to do!.
    }

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
    {
        var newBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        newBounds.size.height = 10 //Size of your track 
        return newBounds
    }
}
```